# Slash instead of dash for year ranges

Tags: biblatex

First a MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[utf8, backend=biber, style=caspervector-ay]{biblatex}
%the style set alldates=iso in default

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{bookot,
        location  = {Place},
        publisher = {ABC},
        author    = {Name, Given},
        title     = {One title},
        year      = {2001},
    }
    @book{bookat,
        location  = {Place},
        publisher = {ABC},
        author    = {Name, Given},
        title     = {Another title},
        date      = {2001/2009},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    some quote from \cite{bookot,bookat}
    
    some quote from \parencite{bookot,bookat}
    
    some quote from \textcite{bookot,bookat}
    
    some quote from \textcite{bookot}
    
    some quote from \parencite*{bookot}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the symbol for date ranges is `-` but not `/` in the `caspervector-ay` style, i.e., it's 2001-2009. Then how to make the symbol for date ranges be `/`, i.e., make 2001-2009 be 2001/2009 as in the ISO?

Answer (score 3):

The date range separator is controlled by `\bibdaterangesep` (in the `iso` date format `\bibdaterangesep` is not used: there the slash is hard-coded). You can redefine it as follows

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibdaterangesep}{\slash}
```

Comment: It's strange that `\printlabeldateextra` in `date+extradate` changes  `\bibdaterangesep` in date but not in `eventdate`, `origdate` and so on.

Comment: @M.Logic `iso` date formats don't use `\bibdaterangesep`. They have a hard-coded slash. Your style sets all dates except `labeldate` to `iso` format. `labeldate` is in the format `year`, which uses the normal `\bibdaterangesep`.